# Get the best of two Arrays

Tags: code-golf, math, number, array

You will be given two arrays of floating-point numbers. Your task is to pair the corresponding elements of the two arrays, and get the maximum of each pair. *However*, if the two corresponding elements are equal, you must take their sum instead.

For example, given the lists `[1, 3, 3.2, 2.3]` and `[3, 1, 3.2, 2.6]`, you must do the following:

- Pair the elements (or zip): `[[1, 3], [3, 1], [3.2, 3.2], [2.3, 2.6]]`.
- Go through each pair and apply the process above: `[3, 3, 6.4, 2.6]`.

---

### Specs

- The arrays / lists will always have equal length. They may however be empty.
- The numbers they contain will always fit your language's capabilities, as long as you do not abuse that. They may be positive, zero or negative, you must handle all types.
- If it helps you reduce your byte count, you *may* also take the length of the lists as input.

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
- [Standard input and output rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) apply. You may take input (and output) in any reasonable format.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

---

## Test Cases

```
Array_1, Array_2 -> Output

[], [] -> []
[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2] -> [2, 3, 3]
[1, 3, 3.2, 2.3], [3, 1, 3.2, 2.6] -> [3, 3, 6.4, 2.6]
[1,2,3,4,5,5,7,8,9,10], [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] -> [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 10, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[-3.2, -3.2, -2.4, 7, -10.1], [100, -3.2, 2.4, -7, -10.1] -> [100, -6.4, 2.4, 7, -20.2]
```

Comment: You say that the numbers will always fit "within your language's" capabilities".  As long as you do not "abuse" that.  Would only supporting integers in a language that does not have floats be considered an abuse?  The question does say floating point but I don't really see a reason why it has to be floats.  The same process can be done on integers.  I would like to solve this in Brain-Flak but Brain-flak only supports ints.

Comment: @WheatWizard I can make an exception for that. Go ahead and post your answer and mention I allowed it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Jelly, 4 bytes

```
=‘×»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/2UcOMw9MP7f7//3@0oY6xjrGekY6RnnHs/2hjHUMozywWAA)

This uses the exact same approach as [my APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140820/55550), except Jelly has a builtin for adding one to a number!

Comment: Hate to be a spoilsport, but aren't some of those characters more than one byte each in any sensible encoding?

Comment: This uses the [jelly codepage](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

Comment: I finally won against competition!

Comment: @Zacharý ONE MAN, 4 btytes... THIS SUMMER... You... WILL... **BE**... ***JELLY OF HIM***... *rated J for Jelly*.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 45 bytes

A mix of my initial solution and [@ovs'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140754/59487).

```python
lambda*a:map(lambda x,y:max(x,y)*-~(x==y),*a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LCoMwEEX3/YrZGWUiSbRqBfsjaRYpRRqoD8SFbvrr6RirBCb33jOPcZ3fQ6982zz8x3bPl01s3dmR7QYWXMkujP444V@2NM0aY2Jj3w4TOHA9aK0NgjZb0RJBIWSbJpmRO3MyWUpQpQGTlWdSHF0KM8zxSq/ECm8oRVglSFYUFQRyalEo9wkeFvyrSnOEkoQUqdznxAED4yc0pr7AOLl@BocRv0fYMqfpmNPSxP4H)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:[max(a,b)*-~(a==b)for a,b in zip(x,y)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NCoMwEITvfYq9NZaNmMSqFeyLpDlEijRQfxAP2kNf3W5ilcAy883sZlimV9/Jtake69u29dPCjEupWzszi3V04V9mq6qOmn4EAuA6@LiBUSkyq4fOI621QdDGDy0QJILymqQid3AyKqZQxiEmKw6S7S2JClO80suxwBuKJJxKSBaEMgpSqkgU2wYPB/5TxilCTkIksdj2kj0MGT9CY8oTDKPrJnB45vczNsxp@sxpYaL1Bw)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 46 bytes

[@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs) suggested this method to save 3 bytes.

```python
lambda*x:[max(a,b)*-~(a==b)for a,b in zip(*x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LCoMwEEX3/YrZNcooeVi1gv2RNItIkQbqA3Fhu@iv20msEhjunDMzGd/zc@jl2tb39WW75mHjpdKdXZjFJoqTL7N13UTtMAEBcD183MjiJTKrZ84TrbVB0MYXLRAkgvKZoqLu4NSolKRMg6ZWHCTfpyQqzPBCr8ASryh4OMUploRyEhmNSBTbRhIO/KtMM4SCguCp2Pb4LoNLDmlMdYJxcv0MDs/J7Ywtc5o@c1qYaP0B)

---

## How?

First off, we pair the corresponding elements, by using either `*` or `zip()`. That allows us to do our further golfing by working either with a map or a list comprehension.

The cool trick in this answer is this part: `max(x,y)*-~(x==y)`. **How does that work?** - Well, as most of you already know, Python auto-converts bool values to integers when they are used in arithmetic operations. Hence, `(x==y)` gets evaluated as `1`, if the condition is met. However, if the two values are not equal, it returns `0` instead. Then, the bitwise operation `-~` increments the value returned from the bool by `1`, giving us either `2` or `1`. `max(a,b)` gives the maximum value of the pair and `*` multiplies it by the value returned above (so it gets multiplied by `2` only if they are equal, in which case `max()` returns the value of both).

This is based on the fact that the sum of two equal numbers is in fact either of them doubled, and kind of "abuses" Python's bool class being a subclass of int.

Comment: Wow, that was really fast!

Comment: more straightforward, same number of bytes: `lambda*a:map(lambda x,y:(x<=y)*y+(x>=y)*x,*a)`

Comment: @jferard I fact, that's already Luis' solution.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Oops! I didn't read the whole page...

Comment: Never say "above," as the ordering can change (I don't see your solution above)

Comment: This isn't weak typing or converting booleans to ints. In Python the bool class is an actual subclass of int.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>48</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @nwellnhof*

```python
lambda*a:map(lambda*x:max(x)*2/len({*x}),*a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/dDoIwDIXvfYreuS1l7gdFTfRFcBczSiQBJIQLDOHZZxlKlnTnnK9t0vbTv96NDcXlFipf3x9e@HPtW/YzA5mBDVyYXfVs2CiGiaPwPBTvDjzeoWwgzx3mziEJjWAQ7KxJWnJrTsZKgkZGTFavyeHfZdBiint6GR7xhFrFVYrkkaIDgZRaDOplIokLftXIFCEjoZXUy5z6w8iSFbrzBqDtyqZn23FCGCdIrlS3ku6qfc/oNMxFMf/ccR6@)

Answer (score 11):

## Kotlin, <s>78</s> <s>75</s> <s>71</s> <s>66</s> <s>65</s> 59 bytes

It's my first attempt, be cool :D

```
a.zip(b).map{(a,b)->when{b>a->b;a>b->a;else->a*2}}.toList()
```

**TIO doesn't work with this solution (and i don't know why), source code for testing below**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    bestOfTwo(floatArrayOf(), floatArrayOf()).print()
    bestOfTwo(floatArrayOf(0F), floatArrayOf(0F)).print()
    bestOfTwo(floatArrayOf(1F,2F,3F), floatArrayOf(1F,3F,2F)).print()
    bestOfTwo(floatArrayOf(1F,3F,3.2F,2.3F), floatArrayOf(3F,1F,3.2F,2.6F)).print()
    bestOfTwo(floatArrayOf(1F,2F,3F,4F,5F,5F,7F,8F,9F,10F), floatArrayOf(10F,9F,8F,7F,6F,5F,4F,3F,2F,1F)).print()
    bestOfTwo(floatArrayOf(-3.2F,-3.2F,-2.4F,7F,-10.1F), floatArrayOf(100F,-3.2F,2.4F,-7F,-10.1F)).print()
}


fun bestOfTwo(a :FloatArray, b :FloatArray): List<Float> =
    a.zip(b).map{(a,b)->when{b>a->b;a>b->a;else->a*2}}.toList()


fun List<Float>.print() {
    this.forEach { print("$it, ") }; println("")
}
```

**EDIT:**

-3 by replace "a+b[i]" by "a*2"

-4 by replace "mapIndexed" method by "zip" *(Thanks to @AnonymousReality 
 Swift solution)*

-5 by replace "Math.max" method by when condition

-1 by change when condition order

-6 by change toFloatArray() by toList()

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Please don't be discouraged by the downvote (it's the result of a slight quirk of the system that happens when a new user's first post is auto-flagged for quality and then they improve said post!!)

Comment: The worst "feature" ever...btw don't feel bad about it.

Comment: Link to Kotlin Playground: https://pl.kotl.in/Qne3U_j4l

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>53</s> <s>49</s> <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```
a=>b=>a.map((x,y)=>(y=b[y])>x?y:y<x?x:x+y)
```

- 4 bytes saved by borrowing a trick from Mr. Xcoder.
- 2 bytes saved thanks to Arnauld.

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=(f=

a=>b=>a.map((x,y)=>(y=b[y])>x?y:y<x?x:x+y)

)(i.value=[1,3,3.2,2.3])(j.value=[3,1,3.2,2.6]);oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value.split`,`.map(eval))(j.value.split`,`.map(eval))
```

```html
<input id=i><input id=j><pre id=o>
```

---

### Explanation

```
a=>b=>
```

Anonymous function taking the 2 arrays as arguments via parameters `a` and `b`, in currying syntax (i.e., call with `f(a)(b)`

```
a.map((x,y)=>                      )
```

Map over the first array, passing each element through a function where `x` is the current element and `y` is the current index.

```
(y=b[y])
```

Get the element at index `y` in the second array and assign that as the new value of `y`.

```
>x?y
```

Check if `y` is greater than `x` and, if so, return `y`.

```
:y<x?x
```

Else, check if `y` is less than `x` and, if so, return `x`

```
:x+y
```

Else, return the sum of `x` and `y`. (Multiplying `x` or `y` by 2 would also work here, for the same number of bytes.)

Comment: ``j.value.split`,`.map(eval)`` or `eval('['+j.value+']')`? Also `x+y` would look neater IMHO.

Comment: @Neil: 1) I find the former easier to type. Also, I have a couple of Snippet templates on one of my machines; it's easier just to tack `.map(eval)` onto them. 2) Agreed, will edit in momentarily.

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell, 34 bytes

```haskell
x!y|x>y=x|x<y=y|1<2=x+y
zipWith(!)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##VU7BboJAFLzzFSPpAeJCYLGKxjVpkzYxNfHgoQdDIkQMpFasYISGf6ePFSrsbjbvzcybeZGffoXHY1Xlg6LMF4XIy3xeiKK051zkw0I5iN/4/BlnkTbQqzRKrsf9a4jZDNrbD3yGTZTc4OsQC/gwmm@5hqYrPnbtwA4BSvhCBJBH4HzNNtlldYK6/lAV9E@JJIvCyy1Ow670Cer7y3I1g4rhEFraRFOt4p6EIOySga4o3358IpN9IkMO2Hr162y29VrGZuAMjicrh5q@jkvQ6crr3iScm/UUdfY/MO4PO1I8Nkd37uHBmcNG7JnuhLlsymyrzreocgkZEz4iBWd2348UmDK4DBOypWBLVq5EyaMNMOQ6zc/reFIZtmXaMsZqOUkZD66fVcua3RsHbpncq/4A)

Comment: Same byte count: `x!y=max x y+sum[x|x==y]`.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```r
function(a,b)pmax(a,b)+a*!a-b
```

`pmax` takes the parallel maximum of the two (or more) arrays (recycling the shorter as needed).

I was looking at [Luis Mendo's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140748/get-the-best-of-two-arrays#comment344950_140758) and obviously I realized the approach could work for R as well. That got me to 30 bytes, but then I started playing around with different ways of getting indices instead to improve my original answer, and stumbled upon `!a-b` as `TRUE` where `a==b` and `FALSE` otherwise, equivalent to `a==b`. However, for whatever reason, R doesn't require parentheses around `!a-b` as it does for `a==b`, which saved me two bytes.

As mentioned by [JDL in the comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140748/get-the-best-of-two-arrays/140768#comment345380_140768), this works because `!` (negation) has lower precedence than the binary operator `-` in R, which is strange.

[Try it online! (new version)](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJsyA3sQLM0E7UUkzUTfqfppFXmptalJmsYaCpg2BqcqVpJGsY6hjpGGvqgBjGOkZwQQVjINIz0lEw0gPLArmGcBEzTc3/AA)

[Try it online! (original)](https://tio.run/##RYlBCoAgEEX3ncLlTA2SCu08zCgJLrSQhG5v5cLgL95/r7RgW6jZX/HIwOTwTHx3WHgGttZhC5Br2kv0sCL9iFMAD4o0GaQPDOkhhXknNQkte32vGmZDbA8)

Comment: It turns out that unary "!" has lower precedence in R than binary "-", which I think is quite unusual (and I hadn't realised until reading this answer!)

Comment: @JDL yeah I almost always have to open up the R Syntax page while golfing in case of weird quirks like this...and also because I can never remember the precedence of `:` when interacting with arithmetic.

Answer (score 7):

## Dyalog APL, 5 bytes

```
⌈×1+=
```

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=1%203%203.2%202.3%20%28%u2308%D71+%3D%29%203%201%203.2%202.6&run)

### How?

- `⌈`, element-wise maximum of the arguments
- `×`, element-wise multiply
- `1+=`, 1 added to the element-wise equality of the arguments

This works because if the numbers are unequal, `1+=` will be `1`, which when multiplied by the maximum, is the maximum. When the numbers are equal, `1+=` will return `2`, when that is multiplied by the maximum, we get twice the maximum, or the maximum added to itself.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
żSṀE?€
```

A dyadic link taking a list of numbers on each side and returning the resulting list.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///onuCHOxtc7R81rfn//3@0oY6CMRDpGekoGOkZx/6PBvIM4QJmsQA)** or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///onuCHOxtc7R81rQGyDy/XBzKOTnq4cwaQBqIsENUwR0HXTuFRw9zI//@jo6NjdRSiY2N1uBSiow11FIx0FIxBIkCmMZCHkADyjPWAskZ6YHkg1xAuYgZXZqRjrGOiYwqE5joWOpY6hgZgwwyATAugkBlQwgSoxEjHEKpFF2wElDTSM9FRMAcyDA30DCEaDWCSYDlduGRsLAA)*.

#### How?

```
żSṀE?€ - Link: list of numbers L, list of numbers R   e.g. [1,3,3.2,2.3], [3,1,3.2,2.6]
ż      - zip - interleave L & R                       [[1,3],[3,1],[3.2,3.2],[2.3,2.6]]
     € - for each pair:
    ?  - { if:
   E   -   ...condition: equal                          0      0       1         0
 S     -   ...then: sum                                               6.4
  Ṁ    -   ...else: maximum                             3      3                2.6
       - }                                    ... ->   [3     ,3     ,6.4      ,2.6]
```

---

An alternative is [this monadic link](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/70O5HjXvslfT///8fHW2oo2AMRHpGOgpGesaxOtFAniFcwCw2FgA) taking a list of the two lists, also **6 bytes**:

```
+»⁼?"/
```

---

* I don't think I've ever created a test-suite footer almost three times the byte count of the code before!

Comment: [Outgolfed!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140822/55550). +1 for the practically verbatim interpretation of the question.

Comment: ...and I've been caught out be forgetting that `»` vectorises before!

Comment: What else would it do, take the maximum array in some convoluted way?

Comment: No need for any convoluted definitions, Python manages - for example `max([1,1,0],[1,0,3]) -> [1,1,0]` (not `[1,1,3]`).

Comment: So, basically infinite-base?

Comment: No, `max` just returns the maximum of its two inputs, comparing elements starting at the left. It will fail if it reaches un-orderable elements during the comparisons for example (e.g. in py3 `max([1,0,'3'],[1,0,1]) -> Type Error : '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
øεMÃO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8I5zW30PN/v//x8dbaijYAxEekY6CkZ6xrE6CtFAriFcxCw2FgA)

-1 thanks to [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna).

Comment: Nice idea using `γ`!

Comment: @Emigna I really wanted "maximal elements", and `{γθ` is probably the shortest I can get to for that.

Comment: How about `øεMÃO`?

Comment: @Emigna Cool, thanks! (duh why didn't I think of `MÃ`) yay got the lead now :p btw `øεZÃO` would work too

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>80</s> <s>69</s> <s>67</s> <s>66</s> <s>65</s> <s>64</s> 63 bytes

```java
(a,b,l)->{for(;l-->0;)if(a[l]>=b[l])b[l]=a[l]*(a[l]>b[l]?1:2);}
```

Modifies the second input-array instead or returning a new float-array to save bytes.

-11 bytes by taking the length as additional integer-input, which is allowed according to the challenge rules.
-5 bytes thanks to *@OliverGrégoire* (one byte at a time.. xD)
-1 byte indirectly thanks to [*@Shaggy*'s JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140757/52210), by using `a[l]*2` instead of `a[l]+b[l]`.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##rZFNb4JAEIbv/Io5QjNs@PCjLdGmadJbvXg0HlaEZu26S2CxMYbfbmdFJU1LD40JDLsz78z7ZNjwHfd1kanN@uMotoUuDWwox2ojJHsuS76vEudHIa9VaoRW7EWrqt5m5V@a1/MhcVLJqwreuFAHB0Aok5U5TzOY2SvATos1pG4uNTeLJXCEy3GFVg3SS0jYOBQqw41IYQYKJnB0Oa5Qev70kOvSTaTvT4PEE7nLF3I5nawoejZM7P2uzdr7U/gYeUlztGPpKeqVpKHn2SecLcG6c1MK9W6RvJb0imgXRAAq@7zkDk1ykiiWut/S2KoRAq9VzPeVybZM14YVNN9I5bYLZ0a3ju6pwzvrT@E3xxAhRoh6jKkakaDzj2/tT@YWgUU5WbFR3g8Sd7I474gGN99IgA94j2Mc4RAHGGOEYS9VRPUB6Yakv6e@MOjIwtv/rCBA8C9bGFD0x/SGAQv7FndWXz5tV9d0hR3@i7VxmuMX)

```java
(a,b,l)->{          // Method with 2 float-array and integer parameters and no return-type
  for(;l-->0;)      //  Loop over the array
    if(a[l]>=b[l])  //   If the current value in `a` is larger or equal to `b`:
      b[l]=         //   Modify the second input-array:
       a[l]*        //    Use `a` multiplied by:
        (a[l]>b[l]? //     If the current value in `a` is larger than `b`:
          1         //      Multiply by 1
         :          //     Else (`a` is smaller of equal to `b`):
          2)        //      Multiply by 2
                    //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
}                   // End of method
```

Comment: "If it helps you reduce your byte count, you may also take the length of the lists as input." It will definitely reduce your byte-count ;)

Comment: Also, 2 bytes shorter: `a->b->l->{float A,B;for(;l-->0;b[l]=(A=a[l])<B?B:A>B?A:A+B)B=b[l];}`

Comment: And you can save one more byte by putting `float A, B` in the `for` initialization.

Comment: (Sorry to spam) Last but not least: not declaring temp variables is actually shorter... (65 bytes) `a->b->l->{for(;l-->0;)b[l]=a[l]<b[l]?b[l]:a[l]>b[l]?a[l]:2*a[l];}`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Lol, was already in the process of changing that when I saw Shaggy's JavaScript answer using `*2`. :) Thanks either way.

Comment: Good! This'll make this easier: `(a,b,l)->{for(;l-->0;)b[l]=a[l]<b[l]?b[l]:a[l]*(a[l]>b[l]?1:2);}` (64 bytes) xD No, I don't stop :p

Comment: Or this: `(a,b,l)->{for(;l-->0;)if(a[l]>=b[l])b[l]=a[l]*(a[l]>b[l]?1:2);}` (63 bytes)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Lol.. with golfing every byte helps, but that doesn't mean you need to golf it one byte at a time. ;p

Comment: Well, now you know my process of golfing ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
X>tG=s*
```

Input is a two-row matrix, where each row is one of the arrays.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8KuxN22WOv//2hDHQVjINIz0lEw0jO2BnEM4XyzWAA)

#### Explanation

```
X>   % Implicit input. Maximum of each column
t    % Duplicate
G    % Push input
=    % Is equal? Element-wise with broadcast. Gives a two-row matrix
s    % Sum of each column. Gives a row vector containing 1 and 2
*    % Multiply, element-wise. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a.zip(b).map{|x,y|[x+y,x,y][x<=>y]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7dCoMgFL7fUwi7KXYUf1oZrF7EeVEXg10MYjDIVc/ejqYyBP3@zvl8f0a3P7r7TvsBxmVg3@dUjCV7DdOyzuBWM18cILBmvnW9s9u2T@TBCmOBGFueCe3xPR2aACKBKG8hVMhSQgaq/oKeMpQlC3mkIit1GlMhV7PqUPO0BAUVXPE0oKEFwUMnR6hRqtGoMCJBpE3okRaIBtLgQizjAemg4nhcTcMP4i19L4ao4EwcBTyZwaPZzC0@EP8bhyVn0u4/)

The spaceship operator is great.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

Saved a byte as *Erik the Outgolfer* pointed out that a list of lists is valid input.

```
øεMsËi·
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOswzvObfUtPtydeWj7///RusZ6RjoKUNJIz0RHwRzIMDTQM4zlijY0MIDJgaV04XIA)

**Explanation**

```
ø          # zip the lists
 ε         # apply to each pair
  M        # get max
   s       # swap the top 2 elements on the stack
    Ëi     # if all elements are equal
      ·    # double the max
```

Comment: Wow, that was really fast!

Comment: You can save a byte by removing the `‚` and inputting as a pair of a list and a list.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: True. I assumed we weren't allowed to, but I see that the challenge does specify standard I/O rules. Thanks for notifying :)

Comment: @Emigna Tip: don't make rules out of your mind ;)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Yeah I really need to stop doing that. Especially rules which make my programs longer ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
m*eSdhnd{dC
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%2aeSdhnd%7BdC&input=%5B1%2C+3%2C+3.2%2C+2.3%5D%2C+%5B3%2C+1%2C+3.2%2C+2.6%5D&debug=0)**

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
m*eSdhqhdedC
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%2aeSdhqhdedC&input=%5B1%2C+3%2C+3.2%2C+2.3%5D%2C+%5B3%2C+1%2C+3.2%2C+2.6%5D&debug=0)**

**or**

```
m*eSdh!tl{dC
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%2aeSdh%21tl%7BdC&input=%5B1%2C+3%2C+3.2%2C+2.3%5D%2C+%5B3%2C+1%2C+3.2%2C+2.6%5D&debug=0)**

Comment: @Jakube That's Erik's solution already, sadly. I wanted to use that too, but I can't now

Comment: Oh, didn't see that one.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>49</s> <s>46</s> 45 bytes

*3 bytes removed thanks to [@Mr.Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) (splat instead of two arguments), and 1 byte thanks to [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs) (map instead of list comprehension)*

```python
lambda*x:map(lambda a,b:a*(a>=b)+b*(b>=a),*x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcg9CoAwDEDhq3RMYhC04CDUi9QOCVIU/CnioKevBUF4y/fSc83HbnN0Y15l00no7jdJ8MEIay8EMjjFSgl0cIJMN@Z0LvsFniL4ho0t1S2btraBjS9s/tMFDJhf)

Comment: 46 bytes: [`lambda*c:[a*(a>=b)+b*(b>=a)for a,b in zip(*c)]`](https://tio.run/##PchBCoAgEEDRq8xyxiQwoUVgFzEXM4UklEm0qctbq@Bv3i/3tR7Z1uimuvEuC6t58KyQRyfUiEIZHVM8TmAtkDI8qaCaKdRypnxhRG802K@209C1NmjwH81/@kBUXw). Turns out this is quite good too :) - Too bad there is no place for further golfing

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks! Good idea!

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##Pcg9CoAwDEDhq3RMYhC04CDUi9QOCVIU/CnioKevBUF4y/fSc83HbnN0Y15l00no7jdJ8MEIay8EMjjFSgl0cIJMN@Z0LvsFniL4ho0t1S2btraBjS9s/tMFDJhf) by using map instead of zip.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 31 bytes

```
MapThread[If[#==#2,2#,Max@##]&]
```

Answer (score 3):

## J, 7 bytes

```
>.`+@.=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03BVk/BTi9B20HPlosrNTkjX0HDUMFYwVjPSMFIz1hTIU1Bw1jBEMo304QrMQIqMgFLmyqYKZgrWCCkwBAsBWP//w8A)

Takes one list as the left argument and the other as the right.

Luckily, equality is a rank zero operation.

## Explanation

```
>.`+@.=
      =  Compare equality pairwise
    @.   If equal
   +       Sum
>.       (Else) take greater value
```

`@.` isn't *really* an if statement, but in this case it functions as one (it indexes into the gerund `` >.`+ `` based on the result of its right argument and applies that to the input).

Comment: Nice job, I know I couldn't do this, even though you have been[outgolfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140848/55550) by my translation of my APL. >_<

Comment: J really shines here

Comment: @Zacharý rats, well-golfed nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```
Prompt A,B
(ʟA=ʟB)ʟA+max(ʟA,ʟB
```

Too bad lists take up two bytes each...

Comment: You can save two bytes by prompting for `X` and `Y`, then using `ʟX` and `ʟY` to access them, i.e. "`Prompt X,Y:ʟX(ʟX=ʟY)+max(ʟ1,ʟ2`".

Comment: Also, this is currently invalid, since `L1(L1=L2)` attempts to get the element of `L1` at a list, which throws an error. To fix that, swap the order, i.e. `(L1=L2)L1`.

Comment: @ScottMilner Thanks for pointing both of those out.

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 6 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
×+1⊃=↥
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgw5crMeKKgz3ihqUKCmYgW10gW10KZiBbMSAyIDNdIFsxIDMgMl0KZiBbMSAzIDMuMiAyLjNdIFszIDEgMy4yIDIuNl0=)

```
×+1⊃=↥
   ⊃=↥  # elementwise max and equality mask
 +1     # increment
×       # multiply
```

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 36 Byte

```
@(a,b)a.*(a>b)+b.*(b>a)+2.*a.*(a==b)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can save a few bytes with [`@(a,b)max(a,b).*(1+(a==b))`](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EnSTM3sQJM62lpGGprJNraJmlq/k/TiDbUUTAGIj0jHQUjPeNYHYVoINcQLmIWq/kfAA)

Comment: Or better, using your approach, [`@(a,b)a.*(a>=b)+b.*(b>=a)`](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EnSTNRT0sj0c42SVM7CchKsrNN1PyfphFtqKNgDER6RjoKRnrGsToK0UCuIVzELFbzPwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
ms.MZdC
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ms.MZdC&input=%5B%5B1%2C+3%2C+3.2%2C+2.3%5D%2C+%5B3%2C+1%2C+3.2%2C+2.6%5D%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), using Linq 47+18=65 bytes

```cs
x=>y=>x.Zip(y,(a,b)=>a>b?a:b>a?b:b+a).ToArray()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5BS8MwFMfP9lM8iocEY2AbeFhthggeRE8TBEsPL1k2AjWZSaorpZ@9RqFOhgjv8H68H@//V@FSOa/HNhi7g3UXon4tst/EH4x9KzLVYAiw77MQMRoFd61VcL1xrWx0VbMvPNK0CLEtx0MpulIc@IvZk44RZJKWAoVc4VIKXMmlvEDKn9yN99gROhZTxLszG3hEY0mIPhWqakC/C7TPzm6dDa7R/NmbqFNBTdbfCr93Sc9ZzrbE6g@YikAPMwaLNHzOYM4XMNBTIV1nP8JVEigt/ko6z6v@/7T@5HliOtR5ejcM4yc)

## C# (.NET Core), 82 bytes

```cs
x=>y=>l=>{for(int i=0;i<l;i++)x[i]=x[i]>y[i]?x[i]:y[i]>x[i]?y[i]:y[i]*2;return x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9NS8QwEIbP9lcMxUPjxrLbFQ9mkz0IHkRPe/BQeqjddAl0kzVJtSXkt9dEqIciwjC878zDfDTmtlGaT7I@c3OpGw6H0Vh@zl@E/HBJ09XGwMUlxtZWNPDUywZ2R9W/d7yscLQLJ6TFc4Ux1tJpoGykrKPMtUpnoQ@CronYdUSsVmgoRUVjYmNI@6geomJR7cfZ3hREc9trCQPxE5nv@VTiCK@1kJmxWshTWUGtTwa55OpRSaM6nr9pYXn4hmeHHyR/VgFPcYrbTPIvmI8FBxsM2xB5gaHIt@DREgjdzS9wH4E7hBD5a9l1Wrr/F7rF/OjXCPkqDRO999M3)

Comment: You can drop the LINQ answer by a few bytes by [changing namespace System.LINQ to using System.LINQ](https://tio.run/##fY5BS8MwFMfP9lM8iocEY2AbeFhthggeRE8TBEsPL1k2AjWZSaorpZ@9RqFOhgjv8H68H@//V@FSOa/HNhi7g3UXon4tst/EH4x9KzLVYAiw77MQMRoFd61VcL1xrWx0VbMvPNK0CLEtx0MpulIc@IvZk44RZJKWAoVc4VIKXMmlvEDKn9yN99gROhZTxLszG3hEY0mIPhWqakC/C7TPzm6dDa7R/NmbqFNBTdbfCr93Sc9ZzrbE6g@YikAPMwaLNHzOYM4XMNBTIV1nP8JVEigt/ko6z6v@/7T@5HliOtR5ejcM4yc "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Comment: @jkelm yeah, I've been wondering if the 'using System;` is to be included or not like that, I guess not. I'll clean it up

Comment: System.Linq is included in the "Visual C# Interactive Compiler". I am not totally sure about returning `Array` vs `IList` vs `IEnumerable`, but if all are eligible then you can get the byte count to 37 - https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpesYOPpmleam1qUmJSTapOSXwqk7HRAMlglsIjZ2SmkKdj@r7C1q7S1q9CLyizQqNTRSNRJ0rS1S7RLsk@0SrJLtE@yStJO1PxvzcUVUJSZV6KRppGXWh4dW61g6KKjYAzCekZA0kjP2EWhVhMmCZIwRJI0c6nV1AvJdywqSqzU0NRENU0B4qBog1hNNC6ylv8A

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```
(mapcar(lambda(x y)(*(max x y)(if(= x y)2 1)))(read)(read))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYjBCoAgEAXvfcUe33YQdKFbH7NpgaAh1sG@3iK8DDPjU7xKR6nxvKkja/FakTRvQdHoYczfbPRrPLD@5sgyM@quYZA7d1gSEuPIGeEJQnbUwi8)

*-1 byte thanks to @Zacharý!*

Comment: 59 bytes: `(mapcar(lambda(x y)(*(max x y)(if(= x y)2 1)))(read)(read))`.

Comment: You're welcome, I don't know lisp that well, I just translated my other answers into Lisp which ended up saving a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## Python with numpy, 28 bytes

```
lambda a,b:a*(a>=b)+b*(b>=a)
```

Assumes input is given as two numpy arrays.

Comment: If we are using numpy then here is my worse solution: `lambda a,b:n.fmax(a,b)*((a==b)+1)`

Comment: @Erich I like the idea, but to do that I would need to `import numpy as n`. I get away without it here because it's implicit in the input.

Comment: I guess i'm a bit shaky on the explicit byte counting, often python answers are simply lambdas, when an actual implementation of an answer would require assigning it to something. for this reason I wonder if it is allowable to get away with an implicit import statement as well?

Comment: @Erich In general, you can only refer to a variable `n` if you've defined `n` in your code, so imports must be explicit.  By default, we allow [functions or full programs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/48543) as answers, which includes anonymous functions.

Comment: here's an even worser version  `lambda a,b:[max(n) for n in zip(a,b)]*((a==b)+1)` without numpy :p

Comment: Well, this only needs input as numpy arrays, rather than importing `numpy`. But does this even work without using `return`?

Comment: @Zacharý Thanks for pointing that out.  I switched it in testing and forgot to take it out.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>34</s> 28 bytes

```perl6
{map {.max*2/set $_},[Z] $_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzBDsIgEETvfsUeelCzRRaQ1hh/REIMh3qSpGk9aBq/HRfURg3JMjvzdvpuuNgU71Cd4ZCmGHqYRAy3tdqM3RWq0wPd0ec/jSFTS@cIQSFoj5Cl5s371X7xnbOpBUNKFIxXmh37TyvUaHDLr8EWd0iyVEuWLVuWA8OIQvq9rEvheyphEBoWJAW97uUnLFk9h1ySng)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
Zƛ≈[∑|G
```

*-1 byte thanks to [@emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a)*

Add the `ḋ` flag if you want to see the numbers in decimal format.

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJaxpviiYhb4oiRfEciLCIiLCJbLTMuMiwgLTMuMiwgLTIuNCwgNywgLTEwLjFdXG5bMTAwLCAtMy4yLCAyLjQsIC03LCAtMTAuMV0iXQ==)

Explanation:

```
Z        # Zip
 ƛ       # On each pair
   [     # If
  ≈      # All are equal
    ∑    # Sum
     |   # Otherwise
      G  # Get the greatest value
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
₌Þ∴=›*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigozDnuKItD3igLoqIiwiIiwiWzEsIDIsIDNdXG5bMSwgMywgMl0iXQ==)

```
₌      # Do both of these...
 Þ∴    # Elementwise maximum
   =›  # Equality, incremented -> list of 1s where unequal, 2s where equal
     * # Multiply by that.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3, <s>81</s> 79 Bytes

```
func n(a:[Double],b:[Double]){for(x,y)in zip(a,b){print((x==y) ?x+y:max(x,y))}}
```

Swift has an interesting property in that an Int isn't directly castable to a `Double`, so you have to specify any arrays as being arrays of `Double`s before passing them to the function.

(e.g.) `var k:[Double] = [1,2,3,4,5,5,7,8,9,10]`

Edit: -2 bytes thanks to @EriktheOutgolfer

Comment: Do you need spaces around `(x,y)` and before `?`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer The one before `?` is needed because Swift would treat them as optional types instead of ternaries (which they aren't). The others aren't. Apart from that, this can be drastically golfed.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer - TheIOSCoder has already answered you partly, but you're right, you don't need the ones in the for loop, interesting!

Comment: 73 bytes: `func n(a:[Float],b:[Float]){print(zip(a,b).map{$0==$1 ?2*$0:max($0,$1)})}` (the float inaccuracies need not to be handled by default)

Comment: Or 74 bytes: `func n(a:[Float],b:[Float]){print(zip(a,b).map{($0==$1 ?2:1)*max($0,$1)})}`

Comment: I got a 41 byte swift answer, check it out: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143367/11490

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>76</s> 75 bytes

*Thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen for saving a byte!*

```
f(a,b,n)float*a,*b;{for(;n--;++a,++b)printf("%f ",*a>*b?*a:*b>*a?*b:*a*2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDdaoNAEEbvfYpFKOyuo7irJmmWJg9SejEbMARaE1J7JT67/Wpi/QFdRmTmzHcWT/H5dOq6UjJ5qlT5eeVaM2nvmvJ6l66KYxdFTFHk1e1@qepShi@lCEnzQfuj5r32B81H7featVWu7QCJL75UUgVNIPD0oYLN@4d4E03rJk2/aEo2hCaJVLnbT/0tw1C5YJpiHwtALIlsHjbOMozHTJD@j17LzKZ7WQLUJovoJ4K5@Uc2owF9j8rXDPlgsJRRTgXOlnb0SiadewYwxWwHZgMyx44lM9py2FBm9ScVj5S4v@jzbROsbPFh0sTMpcUgTQe6h@MlLbmAGVXA13a/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 bytes

```
íV,È¥Y Ä *XwY
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=7VYsyKVZIMQgKlh3WQ==&input=Wy0zLjIsIC0zLjIsIC0yLjQsIDcsIC0xMC4xXQpbMTAwLCAtMy4yLCAyLjQsIC03LCAtMTAuMV0KLVE=) with the `-Q` flag to format the output array.

Comment: Nicely done. I made 2 attempts at this earlier with both coming out at 17 bytes. I'd forgotten `í` could take a function as a second argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>107</s> 97 bytes

```rust
|a:V,b:V|a.iter().zip(b).map(|(&x,y)|if x==y{x+y}else{x.max(y)}).collect::<V>();
type V=Vec<f32>;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDRboIwFH2Wr7j6sLRZqW1hiijuL3hZfEBSEhJkRNkCA76dtbUqL5tJz2177r2n5/b8danHrIRTkpcIQ@fMCllDFo19EsbkGMZ9QvNanhGmP3mFjpiekgr16KUhLe7zDJooarvmtR1kcZFdo9INavGAafpZFDKtw3AX7xHeOnVbSYijWKa7zBP77TirznlZF@UcLbrwfVgQyNC3TOcIE7juGG9huYSPg/NnLaeMgNDBo@zWyO3dZO4qQnFqPRPzrkHoZu@maEg@yazusp6RXVHf0E/UtVOt5Su8WawVAoWNAmeTKZglA1u0sg2@FdFifDIgV/Y2BAICa2VI@WXmFBiWs3@suWYqG4UeRb8HrrLAH3aY4ewHqBp3UvTwoCn7G7553xWMioMzjL8)

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to @mgc*

Comment: I guess you can save 8 bytes by using type inference on the collected `Vec` and by using the `max` method of `f32`s: `|a:Vec<f32>,b:Vec<f32>|a.iter().zip(b).map(|(&x,y)|if x==y{x+y}else{x.max(y)}).collect::<Vec<_>>();`

Comment: @mgc Thanks! Type inference was a good idea, but in this case type alias is even shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 6 bytes

```
>.*1+=
```

A direct translation of my APL answer (and thus works the same as my MY and Jelly answers). Any tips are welcome, since I don't really know J.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1/BUMFYwVjPSMFIz1hBw05Py1DbVhMoZAgVNPv//z8A)

### Comparison with APL

```
>.*1+=
⌈ ×1+=
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 61 Bytes

```
x=>y=>x zip y map(v=>if(v._1==v._2)v._1*2 else v._1 max v._2)
```

The above is a function literal in Scala. Here's an explanation.

```
x=>y=>         // Function literal taking 2 * Vector[Float], x and y.
x zip y        // Zip x and y into one list of pairs.
map(           // Replace every element in the list via a function.
v=>            // Function literal that takes a pair of floats.
if(v._1==v._2) // If the pair are equal.
v._1*2         // Set the element to the first member of the pair multiplied by 2.
else           // Otherwise.
v._1 max v._2) // Set it to their max.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift 4](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59c354d66032437898077551), 41 bytes

```
{zip($0,$1).map{$0==$1 ?2*$0:max($0,$1)}}
```

[Test cases:](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59c354d66032437898077551)

```
let f: ([Float], [Float]) -> [Float]
    = {zip($0,$1).map{$0==$1 ?2*$0:max($0,$1)}}

let testcases: [(inputA: [Float], inputB: [Float], expected: [Float])] = [
    (
        inputA: [],
        inputB: [],
        expected: []
    ),
    (
        inputA: [1, 2, 3],
        inputB: [1, 3, 2],
        expected: [2, 3, 3]
    ),
    (
        inputA: [1, 3, 3.2, 2.3],
        inputB:  [3, 1, 3.2, 2.6],
        expected: [3, 3, 6.4, 2.6]
    ),
    (
        inputA: [1,2,3,4,5,5,7,8,9,10],
        inputB:  [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
        expected: [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 10, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    ),
    (
        inputA: [-3.2, -3.2, -2.4, 7, -10.1],
        inputB:  [100, -3.2, 2.4, -7, -10.1],
        expected: [100, -6.4, 2.4, 7, -20.2]
    ),
]

for (caseNumber, testcase) in testcases.enumerated() {
    let actual = f(testcase.inputA, testcase.inputB)
    assert(actual == testcase.expected,
        "Testcase #\(caseNumber) \((testcase.inputA, testcase.inputB)) failed. Got \(actual), but expected \(testcase.expected)!")
    print("Testcase #\(caseNumber) passed!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç√'8½B=☺
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80fb2738ab423d01&i=%5B%5D,%5B%5D%0A%5B1,+2,+3%5D,+%5B1,+3,+2%5D%0A%5B1,+3,+3.2,+2.3%5D,+%5B3,+1,+3.2,+2.6%5D%0A%5B1,2,3,4,5,5,7,8,9,10%5D,+%5B10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1%5D%0A%5B-3.2,+-3.2,+-2.4,+7,+-10.1%5D,+%5B100,+-3.2,+2.4,+-7,+-10.1%5D&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 26 bytes

```
f(a,b)=\{a=b:2a,a>b:a,b\}
```

Leading newline necessary.

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/c5oxja4vrz)

Comment: In your TIO link, you might want to give an example giving it lists instead of numbers, like so: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iil8pysjzu

Comment: @Steffan `L1` and `L2` are lists, they’re just defined through the table’s first two columns, and then the third column shows `f(L1, L2)` which is the result of passing the function the two lists. Desmos isn’t evaluating it row by row as it may initially seem

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://python.org), <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[x==y and x+y or max(x,y)for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

### Generators, <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:(x==y and x+y or max(x,y)for x,y in zip(a,b))
```

-1 each by Steffan

Comment: -1 byte using `and` and `or`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7RboMwDEXf@Qq/kWwmCqGjtBL9EcZDKkCNBAQBmmA/z5yEVZGS63Ov7Uz7@rJjdnTl99Hr4dlo0Pi8V1tZ7qDHBrbPHewMg97YhjvvSNMLZoRfMzHK8vrw0CE7tSOTGM8xF3OrG8bFMvVm7c3YLozfIzBoy0FPrP3RPW7BZTEkD4g5j2CazbiyD4Nx8ojREtHL0s4rdAR5WdqjqhGq2jVUdVSlCAohc4xkRlWwlC@ykHBKEFHCB6lM3yQP@cyncnEJzLUpzPCCX3SuWOANU@m3SJIFoZyMC0UUpmEEOXBDKBCuNIl2SK8KT6k5qhK/87yV20V@kkqRhsny3/Re8jbP8c4@f3i2KilU/Qc "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used it on my lists and generators solutions.

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

*-1 byte by porting [emanresu A's Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250281/16766)*

```
⌈×1+=
```

Anonymous tacit function that takes equal-length lists as left and right arguments. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oyIw5cxKz0KCuKfqDEsIDMsIDMuMiwgMi4z4p+pIEYg4p+oMywgMSwgMy4yLCAyLjbin6k=)

#### Explanation

```
⌈×1+=
    =  Compare the two lists itemwise (1 for equal, 0 for not equal)
  1+   Add 1 to each (2 for equal, 1 for not equal)
⌈       Get the itemwise maximums of the two lists
 ×     Multiply (itemwise)
```

#### Original solution

The spec can be implemented very literally in **6 bytes**:

```
=◶⌈‿+¨
      ¨  Apply this function to corresponding pairs of elements from the arguments:
=          Test if the elements are equal (1 if so, 0 if not)
 ◶         Use that result to pick a function from this list and apply it:
  ⌈         If 0 (not equal), then max
   ‿+      If 1 (equal), then add
```

Comment: Turns out I unintentionally ported the Jelly/APL answers lol.

Comment: Ha--and the APL answer is actually identical to this one!

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 36 bytes

```factor
[ [ 2dup = [ + ] [ max ] if ] 2map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHLbsIwELznK6bnKpbtpIFSlSvqhQvqCXGwgqMimge2kYpQvj2s7Qrc2vLsY3Z2V3Kjateb6XPzsV4toKzta4ujNp3@RqvcVwDWm702sPp01l2tLQajnbsM5tA5vGXZNQOdK90xvBFPyJfevRMCEkWgBVmZFnmi@FNKMZOQLAoKnwlxlcq8qGJlTP@bU@KF7gxzvELwOJaTP6dcRUwZdhBpu4Qn9yG9d879DhEkjZ0hF5yJ3948Mp7IH0zSnAriskEpORWP2ThtsYXcnwe8k/OMHWGrfsgeGgLZqgG7qYn/svQRm24)

Answer (score 1):

## POSIX Shell + Utilities, 40 bytes

```
paste $@|awk '$0=$1<$2?$2:$1>$2?$1:2*$1'
```

"Arrays" defined as "text files per POSIX".
Obviously buggy insofar as `[0], [0] -> []`. Doesn't come up in the validator, so. Append the 2-byte `""` sequence to also handle that edge case.

Transcript of test cases:

```
$ cat cg; echo; wc -c cg
paste $@|awk '$0=$1<$2?$2:$1>$2?$1:2*$1'
40 cg
$ ./cg /dev/null                               /dev/null
$ ./cg <(printf '%s\n' 1 2 3)                  <(printf '%s\n' 1 3 2)
2
3
3
$ ./cg <(printf '%s\n' 1 3 3.2 2.3)            <(printf '%s\n' 3 1 3.2 2.6)
3
3
6.4
2.6
$ ./cg <(printf '%s\n' 1 2 3 4 5 5 7 8 9 10)   <(printf '%s\n' 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
10
9
8
7
6
10
7
8
9
10
$ ./cg <(printf '%s\n' -3.2 -3.2 -2.4 7 -10.1) <(printf '%s\n' 100 -3.2 2.4 -7 -10.1)
100
-6.4
2.4
7
-20.2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 16 bytes

```
{.{a+_:e>\:=)*}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP2fU5dT979arzpRO94q1S7GylZTq7b2f13C/2hDBWMFYz0jBSM941iuaGMFQyjPLBYA)

Oh hey look, my code is cute `:=)` but a big dude `\:=)*`

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 40 bytes

```clj
#(map(fn[x y]((if(= x y)+ max)x y))% %2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBCoAgEAXQvaf4EMIMrdR1JxEXUg4UaSIEdnqr1XvreR13S4O2JJAxUY6VpPiOJxDtQgu@8owcO/9jDW15sFJUWwEJvIGFC/Du0wTm8QI)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 74 bytes

```php
function($a,$b){foreach($a as$i=>$p)echo$p*($p>=$q=$b[$i])+$q*($q>=$p),_;}
```

Prints the results separated by an underscore. [Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e78a008bd7c6b47e37cad6127f0290f8871cee41).

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 80 bytes

```swift
var o = [Int]();for (c, d) in zip(a,b){o.append(c==d ? c*2 : max(c,d))};return o
```

- Create the output array
- zip together a & b
- for each loop through with c & d
- append result to output array
- return output array

Comment: You should be able to remove most of those spaces.

Comment: I got a 41 byte swift answer, check it out: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143367/11490

Answer (score 0):

## MY, 20 bytes

```
αωD6ǵ'69ǵ';ƒ⇹(αω=‘×↵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638///cxvOdLmbHt6qbWQIJ62OTHrXv1AAJ2j5qmHF4@qO2rf///4821FEwBiI9Ix0FIz3j2P/RQJ4hXMAsFgA)

This uses the exact same approach as my APL and Jelly answers, except MY doesn't have some of the builtins:

- `D6ǵ'69ǵ';ƒ`, this pushes `<SPACE>⍐` in MY's codepage (where `<SPACE>` is a physical space) as a function, which turns two items into a list, then finds the maximum.
- `⇹(`, map over each argument, then apply the function.

Answer (score 0):

## K, 12 bytes

```
{x|y*(1+x=y)}
```

Exact same strategy as my other answers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v7qiplJLw1C7wrZSszbaUMFIwdjaUMFEwTj2/38A)

Any golfing tips are welcome, as I don't really know K.

Answer (score 0):

## Erlang, 65 bytes

```
fun(A,B)->lists:zipwith(fun(C,C)->C+C;(D,E)->max(D,E)end,A,B)end
```

example:

```
1> (fun(A,B)->lists:zipwith(fun(C,C)->C+C;(D,E)->max(D,E)end,A,B)end)([1, 3, 3.2, 2.3], [3, 1, 3.2, 2.6] ).
[3,3,6.4,2.6]
```

just a straightforward anonymous fun

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>49</s> 44 bytes

```
transpose|map(if.0==.1then add else max end)
```

Sample input

```
[[], []]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2]]
[[1, 3, 3.2, 2.3], [3, 1, 3.2, 2.6]]
[[1,2,3,4,5,5,7,8,9,10], [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]]
[[-3.2, -3.2, -2.4, 7, -10.1], [100, -3.2, 2.4, -7, -10.1]]
```

Sample run

```
$ jq -Mc 'transpose|map(if.0==.1then add else max end)' input
[]
[2,3,3]
[3,3,6.4,2.6]
[10,9,8,7,6,10,7,8,9,10]
[100,-6.4,2.4,7,-20.2]
```

Character count

```
$ echo -n 'transpose|map(if.0==.1then add else max end)' | wc -c
      44
```

Thanks again to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech) for helping eliminate 5 bytes!

Comment: Is the space in `.[1] then` not omittable?

Comment: 44 bytes: `transpose|map(if.0==.1then add else max end)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 57 bytes

```
proc M A\ B {lmap a $A b $B {expr $a-$b?max($a,$b):2*$a}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NDoIwEITvPsUcelBjm/4goheDd55AORTiDUKDmJCQPnvdihpi2nR3vtmdDnUTguu7GgXyGy6YmtY6WLAcFRjp@@h6MMtZdW7tuGZ2x6rNSW@Z9T645/DAtcDk6Zarn1TQMD5WA03G0jEwQkOL6Buoj0r/pmgfCfZ0DshwhJIxTlKXEUmJJzEbavktj1nzo0VCc1xJod6LcuYR8y8vwws)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 59 + 1 (`-p`) = 60 bytes

```perl
say join$",map$_>($t=$F[$i++])?$_:$_<$t?$t:$_*2,split/ /,<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhKz8zT0VJJzexQCXeTkOlxFbFLVolU1s7VtNeJd5KJd5GpcRepQTI0DLSKS7IySzRV9DXsbH7/1/XWM9IAUIY6ZkomCvoGhroGXIZGhhAREGCulDRf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7rJgIA)

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 120 bytes

An answer using ONLY the `ARYOP` function.

```
DEF B A,B,L
DIM C[L],D%[L]ARYOP 6,C,A,A,B
ARYOP.,A,A,B
ARYOP 1,B,A,C
ARYOP 1,B,C,B
ARYOP 6,D%,B,-1,0ARYOP 4,A,C,D%,A
END
```

Function is called as **B** *array1* **,** *array2* **,** *length*. Output is stored in array1.

### Explanation:

```
'get minimum, sum, and maximum of B and A
ARYOP #AOPCLP,C,A,A,B 'c=clamp(a,a,b) (gets the minimum of a and b)
ARYOP #AOPADD,A,A,B 'a=a+b (get the sum)
ARYOP #AOPSUB,B,A,C 'b=a-c (get the maximum)
'check if min==max
ARYOP #AOPSUB,B,C,B 'b=c-c (min-max, will be negative or 0)
ARYOP #AOPCLP,D%,B,-1,0 'd%=clamp(b,-1,0) (d% is an integer array. 0=equal, -1=not equal)
'add subtract min from sum if elements were not equal
ARYOP #AOPMAD,A,C,D%,A 'a=c*d%+a
```

This challenge seemed boring at first, but there are actually a lot of different ways to do it. For example:

-calculate the maximum, add the minimum if B==A

-calculate the sum, subtract A if A<B, subtract B if B<A

-b+max(a-b,0)+a*(a==b)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 15 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
(⊣⌈⊢×1+⊣=⊢)/¨,¨
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=03jUtfhRT8ejrkWHpxtqAzm2QKam/qEVOodWAAA&f=M1QwVjDWM1Iw0jNWSAOyDaE8MwA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Can be golfed as:

```
((⌈×1+=)/¨,¨)
⌈×1+=
```

So it ends up being the same as the other APL answer...